# difference between char *(arr[5]) and char (*arr)[5]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

It appears that I don't practically know the difference between
`char *(arr[5])` and `char (*arr)[5]`
Logically, as it is with type-definitions, `char *(arr[5])` is a pointer to an array of 5 `char`'s, `char *arr[5]` is an array of `char` pointers then what `(*arr)[5]` will be then? Or it makes no difference ?

---

I did some tests and found out that these 3 declarations are different.
For instance if I use `char (*arr)[5]` it totally allows me to do that `arr = malloc(2)`, otherwise it moans about illegal conversions.

---

Can someone explain the differences between these declarations, when they are used and it will be a huge plus if this also includes may I do `arr = malloc(2)` to dynamically allocate an array of [5] chars, as it allows me to semantically do so with `char (*arr)[5]` although giving me stack overflows when being used. *(disclaimer: `[]` suggests stack allocation, so it doesn't make much sense as a heap memory address cannot point to stack memory address as far as I am not aware)*

Comment: `char (*arr)[5]` is a pointer to an array of 5 `char`s... I think `char *(arr[5])` is just an array of 5 pointers to `char`, same as without the parentheses?

Comment: @Dmitri true that makes sense, but EiC c-interpreter finds them for different. This is where I got confused.

Comment: `char (*arr)[5]` and `char *(arr[5])` *are* different.  It's `char *(arr[5])` and `char *arr[5]` that I think are the same.

Comment: I concur with @Dmitri. Since [] already has higher precedence than *, `char *(arr[5])` and `char *arr[5]` must be the same.

Comment: @Dmitri Ahh yes, these two are the same, yeah. So I cannot dynamically allocate a pointer to [5] chars ? Make sense but why technically ? And the interpreter allows it for some reasons.

Comment: If you just want to dynamically allocate an array of 5 `char`s, you just need a regular `char` pointer: `char *arr = malloc(5);`.  You might want a pointer to arrays of chars if you were allocating an array of arrays of `char`, though: `char (*arr)[5] = malloc(10 * sizeof(*arr));` for an array of 10 arrays of 5 `char`s.

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, an array of arrays of char is what I meant. Oh so this is legal.. I just forgot about it and seems that I couldn't find it anymore in the internet. By the way isn't sizeof(*arr) just 5 in this case

Answer (score 0):

`char *(arr[5])` equals to `char *arr[5]` and it means you have array of pointers that each of them points to a character so `arr[0]` can points to a character and `arr[1]` can points to a character and so on.
For example you can write your code like this:

```
char *(arr[5]);// or char *arr[5]
char a = 'a',b='b',c='c';
arr[0] = &a;
arr[1] = &b;
arr[2] = &c;    
printf("a=%c b=%c c=%c \n",*arr[0],*arr[1],*arr[2]);
```

But `(*arr)[5]` means you have an array of 5 characters and you want to point it.
For example you can write your code like this:

```
char (*arr)[5];
char str[5] = "Hell";
arr = &str;
printf("%s\n",*arr);
```